# Is $S=\{ x^2+x+2, 2x^2+x, 3x^2+2x+2\}$ a basis for $\mathcal P_2$ or $\mathcal P_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying to figure out if this is a basis for $\mathcal P_2$ or $\mathcal 3$. Here is my work so far.

Is the set $S$ independent?

$\alpha_1(x^2+x+2) + \alpha_2(2x^2+x) + \alpha_3(3x^2+2x+2) = 0$
$$2(\alpha_1+\alpha_3) + (\alpha_1+\alpha_2)x + 2\alpha_3x + 2\alpha_2x^2 + 3\alpha_3x^2= 0$$

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}2\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_3 = 0, \alpha_1 = 0\\
    \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 0, \alpha_2 = 0\\a3 = 0\\\alpha_1 = 0\\\alpha_2 = 0\\\alpha_3 = 0\end{aligned}\end{equation}

Trivial solution.

Does the set $S$ span $\mathcal P_2$ or $\mathcal P_3$?

$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\0&1&2\\2&2&3\end{bmatrix}$ = matrix of coefficients

$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\0&1&2\\0&1&2\end{bmatrix}$  $R_3-R_1=R_3$

$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\0&1&2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ $R_2-R_3=R_2$

Only $2$ non-zero rows, p2 does span but p3 does not span. In order to span p2 there must be at least 2 linear independent elements, 3 linear independent elements for p3.

Is this correct?

Comment: And what are $p_2$ and $p_3$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The instructor gave the following question. 1.(4pts)Show that S = {x2+x + 2, 2x2+x, 3x2+2x+2} a basis for P2by showing that S is linearly independent and spans P2.Show this by showing that S satisfies the definition of independence and spanning set –do not use theorems. The question after asks if its a basis for p3

Comment: $P_2$ is a frustrating notation since it is not clear if this is the two-dimensional space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $1$., or if this is the three-dimensional space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$.  It is surely one of these, but some authors use it to mean to one while others use it to mean the other.

Comment: It is obviously not a basis for the space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $3$ since it contains no terms who involve $x^3$ in any way.  It is obviously not a basis for the space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $1$ since it contains terms who involve $x^2$.  The only possible confusion should be whether or not it could be a basis for the three-dimensional space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$.  But... it should be clear that these are linearly dependent (*add the first two to get the third*) and so can't be a basis for anything.

Comment: As for your "attempt" showing these are dependent/independent... remember the goal is not to show that the trivial solution is *a* solution (*it is always a solution*), the goal is to show that it is the *only* solution.  You made some hasty conclusions about $a_1=0$ as well as the others...

Comment: So how do I show its the only solution? I am very confused by this whole topic. The transition to online learning due to covid 19 has really affected my learning in this class.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a basis for anything because it's a linearly dependent set: $(x^2+x+2)+(2x^2+x)=3x^2+2x+2$.

To have a basis for $P_3$ you would need $4$ vectors, btw.

Comment: Why are you adding the first two equal to the third?

Comment: That shows the set is linearly dependent.

Comment: Is that how you figure out if the set is dependent for all problems similar to the one I posted above?

Comment: It's an equivalent way of doing it.  The existence of a nontrivial linear combination equal to zero is equivalent to one of the vectors being in the span of the others.

Comment: I see. It seems that the way you did it is much faster than the other way.

Comment: I noticed it...